# Prevent anti-aliasing for imshow in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, blurry

When I use matplotlib's imshow() method to represent a small numpy matrix, it ends up doing some smoothing between pixels.  Is there any way to disables this?  It makes my figure's misleading in presentations.[image: A 28x28 matrix plotted with imshow()]

The figure above is a 28x28 image, so I should be seeing large squares of single colors representing each pixel (as matlab would display it when using imagesc()).  But Instead, the pixels seem to be blurred with neighboring pixels.  Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

There is an interpolation option for `imshow` which controls how and if interpolation will be applied to the rendering of the matrix. If you try

```
imshow(array, interpolation="nearest")
```

you might get something more like you want. As an example

```
A=10*np.eye(10) + np.random.rand(100).reshape(10,10)
imshow(A)
```

[image: imshow(A)]

compared with

```
A=10*np.eye(10) + np.random.rand(100).reshape(10,10)
imshow(A, interpolation="nearest")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work.  Out of curiosity, why is it called 'nearest' for interpolation?  The documentation on this page: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow doesn't describe what 'nearest' does.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. In the development tree there is now also an `interpolation="none"` option which does pretty much the same thing. [This example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/image_interp.html) provides a little more information on what `interpolation="nearest"`is trying to achieve.

Comment: it is maybe trying to sample from the 'nearest' neighbour? in the vicinity of the display pixel

Comment: it is indeed 'nearest neighbour' interpolation

Comment: @ChristopherDorian , just comming here 4 years late, but the difference between nearest and none: http://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_none_vs_nearest.html

Answer (score 20):

you can also try the function

```
matshow
```

which name indicated that it does exactly what you asked - represent matrices.
It is quite handy when you do not need to customise the figure too much.

BTW, one of the best resources for matplotlib is their [Gallery](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/gallery.html)