# Draw Hard Colors in Matplotlib Grid?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a grid based heatmap like the one shown here

[image: heatmap from matplotlib.org]

The code to generate it is [here:](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-image-annotated-heatmap-py)

However, when I run the code (MacOS), I get something very different:

[image: result of the same code run on my machine]

There is much more gradation and the hard edges are all gone. How can I get the hard edges like on matplotlib's website?

Comment: `im = ax.imshow(harvest, interpolation='nearest', cmap='viridis')`.  The example image has `cmap='jet'`, which [isn't a good idea](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAoljeRJ3lU).  Maybe there is a very old version of matplotlib installed?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8376685/10659910), might be helpful

Comment: I ran the example on mac too, I got the expected result. Can you share your matplotlib version?

Comment: @WilliamMiller’s answer helped. @ilke444, how can I tell what version I have? I just have what came with the OS.

Comment: `import matplotlib` `print(matplotlib.__version__)`

Comment: The version seems to be 1.3.1